# Setting Counters for Theorems

Tags: theorems, counters

I'm using the following code to generate the "lemma" functionality in my document:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

However, the first lemma I define appears as `Lemma 0.1`. I tried using the `\setcounter{lemma}` command to change the count, but it didn't work. I want to be able to set the counter so that the first lemma I define appears as `Lemma 5.1`. Note that I'm not working with sections or any other partitioning like that, so the 5 is somewhat arbitrary.

Comment: And how is `theorem` defined? Which document class are you using? This information is relevant, since the counter for your lemmas shares the counter for the theorems.

Comment: You say "Note that I'm not working with sections or any other partitioning like that, so the 5 is somewhat arbitrary." Wouldn't that be confusing for a reader? Usually when the reader sees "Lemma 5.1", the "5" refers to a sectional unit or to another structure in your document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have defined the lemma structure using

```
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
```

this implies that lemmas will share the counter for theorems and, unfortunately, the question doen't give information about how exactly the `theorem` structure was defined. Seeing the form of the counter, however, one can guess that the definition for theorems must be something along the lines of

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
```

where, instead of `[section]` it could be `[chapter]` or similar. In this case, the representation for the counter for lemmas will have a prefix: the counter declared in the second optional argument for theorems and this is the counter you have to change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
test
\end{lemma}

\setcounter{section}{5}
\begin{lemma}
test
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RyanPeden You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that you consider solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).